# Ruby select by index

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to select elements out of an array:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
```

whose index is a Fibonacci number. I want the result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'i', 'n']
```

My code returns both the element and the index.

```
def is_fibonacci?(i, x = 1, y = 0)
  return true if i == x || i == 0
  return false if x > i
  is_fibonacci?(i, x + y, x)
end

arr.each_with_index.select do |val, index|
  is_fibonacci?(index)
end
```

This code returns:

```
[["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["d", 3], ["f", 5], ["i", 8], ["n", 13]]
```

Please help me understand how I can still iterate through the array and evaluate the index but only return the element.

Answer (score 35):

You can change the last bit of your code to

```
arr.select.with_index do |val, index|
  is_fibonacci?(index)
end
```

This works because if you call a method such as `select` without a block, you get an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) object, on which you can then chain more Enumerable methods.

In this case I've used `with_index`, which is very similar to calling `each_with_index` on the original array. However because this happens after the `select` instead of before, `select` returns items from the original array, without the indices appended

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I still wanted to use .select. Thanks so much!

Comment: The answer is right on. I'll just point out that it's a bit more idiomatic to represent an unused variable with an underscore, i.e., `arr.select.with_index do |_, index|`

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems great so far, I wouldn't change it. You can go over your results after the fact and change the `[element, index]` pairs to only contain the `element` by [mapping](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) over each pair and only taking the [first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first):

```
>> results = [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["d", 3], ["f", 5], ["i", 8], ["n", 13]]
>> results.map(&:first)
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "i", "n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

```
index_gen = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i = 0
  j = 1
  loop do
    y.yield i unless i==j
    i, j = j, i + j
  end
end
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa3eb979028>:each> 

arr.values_at(*index_gen.take_while { |n| n < arr.size })
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "i", "n"]
```

or

```
index_gen.take_while { |n| n < arr.size }.map { |n| arr[n] }
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "i", "n"]
```

Note:

- I have assumed Fibonacci numbers begin at zero (rather than one), which is the modern definition.
- The Fibonacci sequence begins `0, 1, 1, 2,...`. The construction of the enumerator `index_gen` skips the second `1`.
- `index_gen.take_while { |n| n < arr.size } #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`